# installing neovim plugins on windows

Tags: lua, neovim

I have to use windows for college reasons, but would like to use neovim as a text editor. I was attempting to install the m4xshen/autoclose plugin using vim-plug, but while I can download the plugin just fine with PlugInstall, it doesn't actually work, and I get an error every time I open neovim.

Here's my init.vim file:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'windwp/nvim-autopairs'

lua require("nvim-autopairs").setup {}

call plug#end()
```

and here is the error that I'm getting:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\eidhn\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim:
line    6:
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: module 'nvim-autopairs' not found:
        no field package.preload['nvim-autopairs']
        no file '.\nvim-autopairs.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\nvim-autopairs.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\lua\nvim-autopairs\init.lua'
        no file '.\nvim-autopairs.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\nvim-autopairs.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Windows, I highly recommend using the WSL on it, which is more suitable to use the terminal-based applications.